# Push, Delete and Print stack elements

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge, python-3.x

I've tried asking about the performance on the HackerRank discussion forum, it didn't work out.

> The task is to write a program with three operations:
>
> ```
>  1 x  Push the element x onto the stack.    
>  2    Delete the element present at the top of the stack.   
>  3    Print the maximum element in the stack.
> ```
>
> The first input line is the number of lines in the program, all subsequent lines are one of the three instructions.

Sample Input:

```
 10
 1 97
 2
 1 20
 2
 1 26
 1 20
 2
 3
 1 91
 3
```

Sample Output:

```
 26
 91
```

My Solution:

```
data = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    ins = input().split()
    if ins[0] == '1':
        data.append(int(ins[1]))
    elif ins[0] == '2':
        data.pop()
    else:
        print(max(data))
```

It gets slow on working with input size of 1000 elements or so,
how could I speed this up?

Comment: You should keep track of the maximum, because using max(data) needs to go through the whole list.

Comment: You should also think of a better title. A title that describes what your code does and not what you want out of a review attracts a lot more views and consequentially also more answers.

Comment: @Graipher Thanks for that It looks much better now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try tracking the current maximum, otherwise frequent occurrences of `3` will push your run time towards \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$.

If you take a closer look at what your input actually means, you will notice that smaller values being pushed onto the stack have actually no significance if a greater value has being pushed previously. So for every fill level of the stack, you already know the corresponding maximum at the time you push onto the stack.

Use that knowledge:

```
current_max = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
    ins = input().split()
    if ins[0] == '1':
        new_max = int(ins[1])
        if current_max and new_max < current_max[-1]:
            new_max = current_max[-1]
        current_max.append(new_max)
    elif ins[0] == '2':
        current_max.pop()
    elif ins[0] == '3':
        print(current_max[-1])
```

By storing the maximum instead of the raw value on the stack, you can always access the current maximum directly. Just don't forget to handle the special case when `data` is empty, so the new value will always be the maximum.

Comment: I agree, the `max` is probably what is killing the time for large lists. However, there should also be a handling in the `pop` part, because you might pop off the maximum value.

Comment: No popping the max value is allowed please see the sample input and sample out @Graipher

Comment: @JøêGrèéñ Well, this is something you should *explicitly* state! Just because it does not happen in your one example does not mean it is not going to happen. The defined instructions would allow for it (and do not say what happens if you *try* to pop the maximum value).

Comment: Can 'new_value = data[-1]' be replaced with 'continue' as both will not let the input mutate the list??

Comment: @JøêGrèéñ The stack is always mutated in case `1`. The only difference is whether you record a max, or a duplicate of the old max. You can't just continue.

Comment: @Graipher Even when the former maximum is popped - the top of `data` still holds the next valid maximum, which is always `<=` the former maximum.

Comment: I don't understand mutating the stack if the data is smaller than the former max??? @Ext3h

Comment: @JøêGrèéñ The size of the stack needs to correspond with the number of push operations specified by the input. If the data is smaller than the current maximum, you still need to push **something** onto the stack. The safest value for that is simply copying the current maximum instead, since the data you just received can never be maximum anyway.

Comment: @Ext3h  ok, I see now. So it is basically what Joop proposed but slightly more clever, because you realized that you don't actually need the values, just the current max (since the pop operation does not return the value, like a normal pop would).

Comment: @Ext3h ran the script with 'continue' and understood the **safe bet** now thanks

Answer (score 3):

One remark. A stack is not a set, you could have the maximal value happening twice. And deletes may happen too.

This in fact means you need a running maximum.

Hence create **a stack of a pair (value, max till now).**

The implementation then is quite simple for all three operations.......

Comment: I havn't used a set sir

Comment: I meant a mathematical set, where all values are unique. The first answer is fine, but ticklish. Because deleting a prior max value can find the same max value if that value was pushed twice. Hence my proposal.

Comment: @JoeWallis it was intended as a warning that a stack can have several max values. So deleting a max value does not automatically give a smaller max value, and adding the same max value needs needs to duplicate that max value. _Must express myself more clear, thanks._

Comment: The actual value is completely irrelevant for this problem. Just recording **"max till now"** is completely sufficient. Which is exactly what the accepted answer does.

Comment: @JoopEggen I failed to understand the bolded part of your answer as I was fixated on the set part. I noticed after posting my comment and so deleted it, in the hopes you'd not have seen it. Your reasoning is definitely clear in your comment.

Comment: @Ext3h yes, I already gave my + for a solid answer.  Though whether `push(5), push(7), push(7) delete(), max() == 7` I did not check - I was not reviewing the answer.